# In C# how to get while loop results outside loop as a String[] array

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite, while-loop

I'm new in C#, I'm using **FiniSar.SQLite** to connect with my **database.db**. i can easily get my while loop results inside loop.

but i want access all results **outside loop** as **String[] array**. i have shared my code with you, i really appreciate that if someone share good answer for me.

File >> **Form1.cs**

```
private void buttonStem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;

    sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
    sqlite_conn.Open();
    sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GList";
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string[] gList;

    while ( sqlite_datareader.Read() )
    {

         gList = sqlite_datareader.GetString(1);
    }

    gList = // { "cat", "dog", "horse" };  << " I want results OutSide Loop something like that "

    sqlite_conn.Close();
}
```

**gList data loss outside loop**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# array have a fixed size, so it would be easier to use a list:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
while (datareader.Read()) {
    list.Add(datareader.GetString(1));
}
```

If you really need an array, you can convert it afterwards:

```
string[] gList = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays should be initialized with the number of elements that you want to put inside that array, then each single element could be inserted in the array in an actual position that goes from zero to the legth of the array less 1. So your code, assuming that you retrieve three elements from the database should be something like this

```
string[] gList = new string[3];
int i = 0;
while ( sqlite_datareader.Read() )
{

     gList[i] = sqlite_datareader.GetString(1);
     i++;
}
```

As you can see this is totally impracticable because it is very difficult to know in advance how many elements are you retrieving from the database (and you should never limit your code in that way). So a better tool is needed. This is the generic collection [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<string> gList = new List<string>();
while ( sqlite_datareader.Read() )
     gList.Add(sqlite_datareader.GetString(1));
```

`List<T>` has no problem adding elements and has many other features that render it preferable to a bare bone array. And, in any case, you could use it as an array in this way

```
foreach(string s in gList)
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

or

```
for(int x = 0; x < gList.Count - 1; x++)
   Console.WriteLine(gList[x]);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, really helpful